# C# : Filtering data of data table using select method

Tags: c#, select, datatable, row

I have data table containing one column as FilePath.

> FilePath 
> D:\New folder\link.txt 
> D:\New
>   folder\SharepointMigration(Work
>   Schedule).xls 
> D:\New
>   folder\my2\link.txt
>  D:\New
>   folder\my2\SharepointMigration(Work
>   Schedule).xls 
> D:\New
>   folder\my2\my3\New Text Document.txt
>   
> D:\New folder\Try.txt

I am filtering my data table by

```
DataRow[] dtRow = dataTable_FilesWithMetaData.Select("FilePath Like '" + sourcePath + "%'");
```

But it gives me all files and subfolder files. But i want only files not subfolders. How to write such type of filter expression..??

EDIT: I am using VS-2008 2.0 framework. 
**The files are coming from some server in xml format and then i am populating my gridview.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If LINQ is available:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(@"D:\New folder\link.txt");
dt.Rows.Add(@"D:\New folder\my2\link.txt");

string target = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"D:\New folder\");

DataRow[] rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(dr =>
    Path.GetDirectoryName(((string)dr["FilePath"])).Equals(target))
    .ToArray();
```

This will only return the row containing (`"D:\New folder\link.txt"`).

In .NET 2.0 you can create a helper method, something like this:

```
public static DataRow[] GetRowsForDir(DataTable table, string targetDir)
{
    var result = new List<DataRow>();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        if (Path.GetDirectoryName(((string)row["FilePath"])).Equals(targetDir))
        {
            result.Add(row);
        }
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks João Angelo, Ur helper method works..Good way to do such thing.. Thanks 1s again ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the files are on the machine running the application, why not just do a

```
Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)
```

for the path you want?

Comment: The files are coming from some server in xml format and then i am populating gridview.